# add header inside listview builder as a date separator in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a list view that shows all expenses, and here I want to do something interesting that this listview should be shown with a header inside it..

like, there are 10 entries of same month, header should b shown with month name as a separator...

I have attached an image to make it very clear,

here is my simple code

Is it logically or have some Widget for it

```
class ExpenseModel
{
  String category;
  int amount;
  DateTime date;

  ExpenseModel({required this.category,required this.amount,required this.date});
}
```

```
void createexpenses() {
    expensies.clear();
    int m,d,y;

    for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++) {
      expensies.add(ExpenseModel(
          category: categories[Random().nextInt(6)],
          amount: Random().nextInt(100),
          date:DateTime(2022, Random().nextInt(6)+1, Random().nextInt(28)+1)));
          //here i want to give random date;


    }

    totalexpense=expensies.fold(0, (previousValue, element) {
      return previousValue+element.amount;
    });

    expensies.sort((a,b)=>a.date.compareTo(b.date));

  }
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    createexpenses(); //creating 50 objects of ExpenseModel
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              StatusWidget(amount:totalexpense),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: expensies.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final data = expensies[index];
                          return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                          child: ExpenseTile(data: data),
                        );
                      }))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: where is the date data come from?

Comment: with that function createexpenses...let me include it

Comment: As I have seen almost application has been using such kind of list with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: expensies.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final data = expensies[index];
            String previousDate = index > 0
                ? DateFormat('MMM yyyy').format(expensies[index - 1].date)
                : '';
            String date = DateFormat('MMM yyyy').format(data.date);
            return Column(
              children: [
                date != previousDate
                    ? Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(date),
                      )
                    : SizedBox(),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                  child: ExpenseTile(data: data),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
```

Comment: done what I wanted

Comment: But is there no other predefined widgets for such listview...Like there should be one header that's position is fixed at the top of listview,, and while scrolling down its text to be changed into based on  month name...

Comment: for that you can use [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers)